# How to detect row and relatively go to the cell in next column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote a code to send mails automatically from google sheet. Every day if column Status has the cell "Timing" I want to send email. And it works. But I don't want to send mails to the people that received mail in previous days, so that I created CHECK to fill the another column by 'sent' after sending an email. It failed. I can't detect the row with an emailaddress that program used to go relatively to another column to insert "sent".

Could you help me?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var she = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("basic");
  var startRow = 2;  
  var numRows = 1000;   
  var dataRange = she.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var text = she.getRange("L2"); 
  var message = text.getValues();
  for (i in data) {
    var col = data[i];
    var emailAddress = col[1];    
    var subject = "Project reminder";
    var status = col[3];
    var check = col[8];
    if (status == "Timing"){
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message) && 
check.setValue('sent');} //moment when I want to insert 'sent'
  }
}
```

Updated part of the code:

```
for(var a=0; a < values.length; a++ ){
   if(values[a][1] == "not" && values[a][3] == "Timing"){
     var emailAddress = values[a][0];
     Logger.log("NEED TO SEND AN EMAIL TO  " + values[a][0]);
     var message = messag + " " + values[a][5];
     MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a mini solution for your use case. Just play with it to understand how it works. The `(0,0), (0,1),etc` represent the index number of the array.

Here's the sample table
[image]

```
function checkIfSent(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123454567890abcdefghi").getSheetByName("12345");

  var values = ss.getSheetValues(1, 1, 6, 2);

  for(var i=0; i < values.length; i++ ){
    for(var j=0; j < values.length; j++ ){
      if(values[i][j] == "NOT"){
         Logger.log("NEED TO SEND AN EMAIL TO  " + values[i][0]);
         //Send an Email method here()
         //. . .
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the values under column **CHECK** are labeled as NOT, you can place your method to send an email to that person (`values[i][0]`).

Comment: Thank you, you solution gave me the idea. But iteration in two dimensions wasn't necessary. I updated code, but still I cannot use setValue("sent")